# Check checkbox when clicking on description

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I will be creating a list of check boxes that will be built by jQuery and JSON. The list will be a selection of groups that a message can be sent to. It could be one of more groups. This part I can figure out. The problem I am having is how do I enable the description so that when I click on the description, the checkbox is selected.

```
<div>
    <label for="group">
        Select lists
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group" value="1" title="Main List" />Main List
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group" value="2" title="Secondary List" />Secondary List
</div>
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use a Label with `for` attribute (I assigned different IDs for checkboxes) :

```
<div>
    <label for="group">
        Select lists
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group1" value="1" title="Main List" />
    <label for="group1">Main List</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group2" value="2" title="Secondary List" />
    <label for="group2">Secondary List</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't mark as answer yet, but this is what I was looking for. I knew something wasn't right, I just couldn't find the answer anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 47):

A different solution (without using the "for" attribute) is including each `<input />` field inside of `<label></label>` tags.

Example:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" /> Click Here to Check This</label>
```

This could a solution if you have to display the checkboxes with labels as `inline-block`.

Answer (score 15):

First: you have a duplicate `id` in there. An `id` should be unique.

The easiest way is to use the [label](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) tag, e.g.:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group" id="group_1" />
<label for="group_1">description</label>
```

Now you can click on the text and it'll toggle the checkbox. An alternative is to use jQuery's `click` function: http://www.google.com/#q=jquery+check+checkbox+on+click.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use jQuery if you don't want to user a 'label'

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="SelectionCheckbox" id="SelectionCheckbox" />  
<div onclick="$('input[id $=SelectionCheckbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);"> 
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label style="cursor:pointer" for="clickme">clickme</label><br>
<span><input id="clickme" type="checkbox"/>anand</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give values to both 'id' in 'input' tag and 'for' in 'label' tag, and both must be same.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="web">
<label for="web">Web research</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="shop">
<label for="shop">Shopping</label>
```